# Creating Html table using perl

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I have a hash in perl whose keys are domain names and value is reference to array of blacklisted zones in which the domain is blacklisted.Currently I am checking the domain against 4 zones.If the domain is blacklisted in the particular zone the I push the zone names in the array.

```
domain1=>(zone1,zone2)
domain2=>(zone1)
domain3=>(zone3,zone4)
domain4=>(zone1,zone2,zone3,zone4)
```

I want to create a HTML table from these values in CGI like

```
domain-names    zone1    zone2   zone3   zone4

domain1         true     true    false   false
domain2         true     false   false   false
domain3         false    false   true    true
domain4         true     true    true    true
```

I tried it using map in CGI like

```
print $q->tbody($q->Tr([
                           $q->td([
                                   map {
                                         map{
                                             $_
                                            }'$_',@{$result{$_}}
                                       }keys %result
                                  ])         
)
```

I am unable to the desired output.I am not sure of using if-else in map.
If I manually generate the td's Then I need to write a separate td's for each condition like

```
If(zone1&&zone2&&!zone3&&!zone4){

  print "<td>true</td><td>true</td><td><false/td><td>false</td>";

  }
  ......
```

It is very tedious.How can I get that output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your Hash of Arrays to a Hash of Hashes.  This makes it easier to test for existence of a particular zone.

The following demonstrates and then displays the data in a simple text table:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Your Hash of Arrays
my %HoA = (
    domain1 => [qw(zone1 zone2)],
    domain2 => [qw(zone1)],
    domain3 => [qw(zone3 zone4)],
    domain4 => [qw(zone1 zone2 zone3 zone4)],
);

# Convert to a Hash of hashes - for easier testing of existance
my %HoH;
$HoH{$_} = { map { $_ => 1 } @{ $HoA{$_} } } for keys %HoA;

# Format and Zone List
my $fmt   = "%-15s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s\n";
my @zones = qw(zone1 zone2 zone3 zone4);

printf $fmt, 'domain-names', @zones;    # Header

for my $domain ( sort keys %HoH ) {
    printf $fmt, $domain, map { $HoH{$domain}{$_} ? 'true' : 'false' } @zones;
}
```

Outputs:

```
domain-names    zone1    zone2    zone3    zone4   
domain1         true     true     false    false   
domain2         true     false    false    false   
domain3         false    false    true     true    
domain4         true     true     true     true
```